# ASP .NET multi file upload selection enable

Tags: .net, jquery

Hi
I'm using the multifile.js from http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/ and it works but the question is how to make the select field multiselect?
I want to be able to select multiple files at once instead of adding them one at a time.
I've tried other upload controls and they dont work with the CMS that i'm using now.
Thanks